# Optimizing gRPC server workload by offloading large data to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, grpc

I have a gRPC client sending large data payloads in its requests to the gRPC server. However, I don't want the server to handle this processing directly due to potential performance bottlenecks. My idea is to leverage Kafka as an intermediary. I want the client to publish the large data to Kafka first, and then the gRPC server will consume and process the data from Kafka asynchronously.

I'm seeking advice on the best practices for implementing this architecture. Specific point I'm interested in is:

Client-side data handling: What's the most efficient way for the client to publish large data to Kafka without overwhelming the server?

Any insights, examples, or resources related to building this architecture would be greatly appreciated!

And actually, I don't want to use Zilla